# Include variable in expression

Tags: yaml, ansible

I'm trying to transfer public keys to linux servers using ansible and it's authorized_key module. I thought I use a lookup to read the content of a file and combine it with items.

```
- name: ensure deployment keys are in authorized keys
  authorized_key: user={{ sshaccess_user }} key="{{ lookup('file', '{{ item }}') }}"
  with_items: sshaccess_keys
```

And sshaccess_keys is defined:

```
sshaccess_keys:
  - ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Obviously, I would like to append more than one. The error I get is

```
fatal: [testbox] => could not locate file in lookup: {{ item }}
```

It tries to read a file instead of taking the content of item as the filename?

Answer (score 1):

When using `with_items` you want to use the `item` variable.  You're using `items`.  Fix that and it looks like this should work.

Comment: unfortunately I have item there. I copied an old version with the new error mesage, so sorry, your solution doesn't work, editing my question